# How to wait after an iteration of a while loop in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, kotlin, sleep, breadth-first-search

I'm programming a path finder visualizer with Kotlin and Java Swing and I have this Breadth-First Search function:

```
fun bfs(): MutableList<Node>? {
    Grid.resetNodes()

    val queue: Queue<Node> = LinkedList()

    queue.add(Grid.start!!)
    Grid.start!!.state = State.IN_QUEUE

    while (queue.isNotEmpty()) {
        val current = queue.poll()
        //println(current)
        current.state = State.CLOSE

        if (current == Grid.end!!) break

        Grid.getNodeNeighbours(current).forEach { node ->
            if (node.state == State.OPEN) {
                node.parent = current
                queue.add(node)
                node.state = State.IN_QUEUE
            }
        }
        GridPanel.repaint()
    }

    return getPath()
}
```

After each iteration of the while loop I want to redraw the Grid and wait a few seconds to make the algorithm view a little slower.
I tried using Swing Timers, but I couldn't get it to work. I can't use 'Thread.sleep()' too because of Java Swing.

Comment: Use coroutines and just insert a delay?

Comment: You can't just insert an algorithm into a Java Swing application.  You have to rewrite the algorithm so one step of the process at a time happens in a javax.swing.Timer ActionListener.

Comment: Swing is a single Thread library. All painting tasks are executed by the 
([EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)). 
Running long processes (such BFS) on the EDT keeps it busy, so it does not do update the gui (gui freezes). Run the long process on a different thread, preferably by using a `SwingWorker`, and there is also when you apply a "wait". See  an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50780369/grid-dfs-visualization/50781879#50781879)

Comment: Another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47494466/3992939)

Answer (score 1):

`Swing` is a single Thread library. All painting tasks are executed by the [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). 
Running long processes (such BFS) on the EDT keeps it busy, so it does not do update the gui (gui becomes unresponsive, freezes). 
Run the long process on a different thread, but remember that all `Swing` gui updates needs to be done by the EDT. 
The different thread is where you can apply a delay for slowing down the process for better visualization.
A good tool to perform such tasks is a `SwingWorker`. 
The following is a single-file [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (copy-paste the entire code to AlgoVisualitation.java and run) demonstrating the basic structure:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingAlgoVisualization {

    private Cell[][] cells;
    private static final int SIZE = 3, GAP = 2;

    JPanel view() {

        JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel();
        gridPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(SIZE, SIZE, GAP, GAP));
        gridPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP,GAP, GAP));
        cells = new Cell[SIZE][SIZE];

        for(int row=0; row <cells.length; row++) {
            for(int col=0; col<cells[row].length; col++) {
                Cell cell = new Cell();
                cells[row][col] = cell;
                gridPanel.add(cell.getComponent());
            }
        }
        return gridPanel;
    }

     void solve()   {
         //run long process on a SwingWorker
         new LongTask().execute();
     }

    //use swing worker to perform long task off the EDT
    class LongTask extends SwingWorker<Void,int[]> {

        private static final long DELAY = 30;
        private final Random rand = new Random();

        @Override
        public Void doInBackground() {
            myLongComplexAlgo();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        //runs on EDT
        protected void process(List<int[]> results) {
            for(int[] result : results){
                cells[result[0]][result[1]].updateValue(result[2]);
            }
        }

        void myLongComplexAlgo() { //simulates long process that repeatedly updates gui

            while (true){ //todo add stop mechanism
                //calculate(apply random value to random cell) and publish results
                int row = rand.nextInt(cells.length);
                int col = rand.nextInt(cells[0].length);
                int value = RandomValue.randomDigit();
                publish(new int[]{row,col,value});

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(DELAY); //visualization delay
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ex.printStackTrace();}
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingAlgoVisualization av = new SwingAlgoVisualization();
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Random Value Change");
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jFrame.add(av.view());
        jFrame.pack();
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
        av.solve();
    }
}

class Cell {

    private static int CELL_SIZE =100, BORDER = 1, FONT_SIZE = 20;

    private final JLabel label;
    Cell() {
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, FONT_SIZE));
        updateValue(RandomValue.randomDigit());
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, BORDER));
        label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CELL_SIZE , CELL_SIZE));
        label.setOpaque(true);
    }

    void updateValue(int value){
        label.setText(String.valueOf(value));
    }

    JComponent getComponent(){
        return label;
    }
}

class RandomValue{

    private static Random rand = new Random();

    public static int randomDigit(){
        return rand.nextInt(10);
    }
}
```

(Run it [online](https://replit.com/@c0derrepo/AlgoVisualization#Main.java))

---

[image]