# Create Delay within GUI in Java

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to visualize a Maze-Generator and i don't know how i can make a delay everytime a Cell/Node is visited. I have read that you shouldn't use Thread.sleep() in a GUI application because it messes with the event dispatch Thread, so i tried utilizing the Swing.Timer, however this also did'nt work out for me. Everytime i tried it, the program just froze and the Window that popped up was blank.

This is the GUI-Class which i use to visualize each step of the Path-finding-Method:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GUI extends JPanel{
    static int frameWidth = 1920;
    static int frameHeight = 1080;
    Timer timer;
    int CELL_SIZE = 30;
    int STROKE_WIDTH = 4;
    int x = 60;
    int y = 30;
    boolean solve = false;
    MazeWilson m;

    public GUI() {
        timer = new Timer(1000,this);
        timer.start();
        m = new MazeWilson(x, y);
        m.generatePath();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(STROKE_WIDTH));
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        for (int i = 0; i < m.height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m.width; j++) {
                g2.drawRect(10 + CELL_SIZE * j, 10 + CELL_SIZE * i, CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE);
            }
        }
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        for (int i = 0; i < m.height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m.width; j++) {
                if (!m.field[i][j].walls[0]) {
                    g2.drawLine(10 + STROKE_WIDTH + CELL_SIZE * j, 10 + CELL_SIZE * (i + 1), 10 - STROKE_WIDTH + CELL_SIZE * (j + 1), 10 + CELL_SIZE * (i + 1));
                }
                if (!m.field[i][j].walls[1]) {
                    g2.drawLine(10 + CELL_SIZE * j, 10 + STROKE_WIDTH + CELL_SIZE * i, 10 + CELL_SIZE * j, 10 - STROKE_WIDTH + CELL_SIZE * (i + 1));
                }
                if (!m.field[i][j].walls[2]) {
                    g2.drawLine(10 + STROKE_WIDTH + CELL_SIZE * j, 10 + CELL_SIZE * i, 10 - STROKE_WIDTH + CELL_SIZE * (j + 1), 10 + CELL_SIZE * i);
                }
                if (!m.field[i][j].walls[3]) {
                    g2.drawLine(10 + CELL_SIZE * (j + 1), 10 + STROKE_WIDTH + CELL_SIZE * i, 10 + CELL_SIZE * (j + 1), 10 - STROKE_WIDTH + CELL_SIZE * (i + 1));
                }
            }
        }

        if (solve) {
            drawSolution(g2);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Maze");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GUI g = new GUI();
        f.add(g);
        JButton solveMaze = new JButton("Lösen");
        solveMaze.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
        solveMaze.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 30));
        solveMaze.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        solveMaze.setOpaque(true);
        f.add(solveMaze, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        f.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.toFront();
    }

    public void drawSolution(Graphics g) {
        Cell c = m.findPath();
        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        for (; c.parent != null; c = c.parent) {
            g.fillRect(10 + STROKE_WIDTH/2 + c.x * CELL_SIZE, 10 + STROKE_WIDTH/2 + c.y * CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE - STROKE_WIDTH, CELL_SIZE - STROKE_WIDTH);

            switch (c.parent.y - c.y) {
            case 1: {
                g.fillRect(10 + STROKE_WIDTH/2 + c.x * CELL_SIZE, 10 + STROKE_WIDTH/2 + c.y * CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE - STROKE_WIDTH, CELL_SIZE + CELL_SIZE/4 - STROKE_WIDTH);
                break;
            }
            case -1: {
                g.fillRect(10 + STROKE_WIDTH/2 + c.x * CELL_SIZE, 10 + STROKE_WIDTH/2 + c.parent.y * CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE - STROKE_WIDTH, CELL_SIZE + CELL_SIZE/4 - STROKE_WIDTH);
                break;
            }
            }
            switch (c.parent.x - c.x ) {

                case 1: {
                    g.fillRect(10 + STROKE_WIDTH/2 + c.x * CELL_SIZE, 10 + STROKE_WIDTH/2 + c.y * CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE + CELL_SIZE/4 - STROKE_WIDTH, CELL_SIZE - STROKE_WIDTH);
                    break;
                }
                case -1: {
                    g.fillRect(10 + STROKE_WIDTH/2 + c.parent.x * CELL_SIZE, 10 + STROKE_WIDTH/2 + c.y * CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE + CELL_SIZE/4 - STROKE_WIDTH, CELL_SIZE - STROKE_WIDTH);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        g.fillRect(10 + STROKE_WIDTH/2 + c.x * CELL_SIZE, 10 + STROKE_WIDTH/2 + c.y * CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE - STROKE_WIDTH, CELL_SIZE - STROKE_WIDTH);

    }
}
```

The generatePath-Method generates the maze and the findPath-Method solves the maze. I want the drawSolution-function to have a delay in each iteration, so that it progressively shows each Cell that is visited during the process.

Comment: Where is the implementation of `ActionListener` ??

Comment: Use a SwingWorker. Then you can use Thread.sleep() and "publish" the results of each iteration of your max. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64196256/131872 for an example of this approach.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68933401/3992939) answer has a full running example of just that.

Comment: Without implementing the `actionPerformed` method, this code shouldn’t even pass the compiler. Besides that, it would be far more readable without those tons of empty lines we have to scroll through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Swing` is a single Thread library. All painting tasks are executed by the [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). 
Running long processes (such path finding) on the EDT keeps it busy, so it does not do update the gui (gui becomes unresponsive, freezes). 
Run the long process on a different thread, but remember that all `Swing` gui updates needs to be done by the EDT. 
The different thread is where you can apply a delay for slowing down the process for better visualization.
A good tool to perform such tasks is a `SwingWorker`. 
You can find an example demonstrating the basic structure [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68933401/3992939).

If you only want to do incremental painting which does not involve long processes you can use a Swing `Timer`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GUI extends JPanel{

    private static final int ROWS = 9, COLS = 6, SIZE = 45, BORDER = 2, DELAY = 500;
    private static final Color BOARD_COLOR = Color.BLACK, CELL = Color.YELLOW, PATH = Color.RED;
    private final List<int[]> directions = Arrays.asList(new int[][] {{1,0},{0,1}} ); // move down or right 
    private final Dimension size;
    private final List<Point> path;
    private final Point start, end;
    private Timer timer;
    public GUI() {
        int x = BORDER + COLS*(SIZE + BORDER);
        int y = BORDER + ROWS*(SIZE + BORDER);

        start = new Point(0,0);
        end = new Point(COLS-1, ROWS-1);
        path = new ArrayList<>();
        path.add(start);

        size = new Dimension(x,y);
        this.initBoard();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return size;
    }
    public void initBoard() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Grid By Painting");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
        timer = new Timer(DELAY, e->incrementPath());
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int width = getWidth(); int height = getHeight();
        int cellWidth = (width - BORDER) / COLS  - BORDER;
        int cellHeight = (height -BORDER)/ ROWS - BORDER ;
        int pathWidth = cellWidth / 4;
        int pathHeight = cellHeight / 4;

        //draw board
        g.setColor(BOARD_COLOR);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        //draw square cells
        for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
                int x = BORDER + col*(cellWidth + BORDER);
                int y = BORDER + row*(cellHeight + BORDER);
                g.setColor(CELL);
                g.fillRect(x, y, cellWidth, cellHeight);

                //draw path
                if(! path.contains( new Point(col,row) )) {
                    continue;
                }
                g.setColor(PATH);
                int xPath = x + cellWidth/2 - pathWidth/2;
                int yPath = y + cellHeight/2 - pathHeight/2;
                g.fillOval(xPath, yPath, pathWidth, pathHeight);
            }
        }
    }

    //construct an arbitrary path for demonstration purposes  
    private void incrementPath() {
        //get a random direction 
        Collections.shuffle(directions);
        int[] direction = directions.get(0);

        Point lastPointInPath = path.get(path.size()-1);
        Point newPoint = new Point(lastPointInPath.x + direction[0], lastPointInPath.y + direction[1]);
        if(! isValid(newPoint) || path.contains(newPoint)) return;
        path.add(newPoint);
        repaint();

        if(newPoint.equals(end)){//found target
            timer.stop();
        }
    }

    private boolean isValid(Point newPoint) {
        return newPoint.x >=0 && newPoint.x < COLS
                && newPoint.y >=0 && newPoint.y < ROWS;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->new GUI());
    }
}
```

---

[image]